# How to get the exact new change in Android contact phone book?

Tags: android, contacts, contentobserver

I am working on android application in which I am saving my phone book in my local db, now what I need is to put the newly added number in my local db from my phone book.

To get the change in my Phone book, I am using `onChange` method in service of `ContentObserver`, but it only triggers that we have some change in phone, not the exact change. My code is given below, how can I get the contact numbers which are added to my phone book, e.g if my total count in DB is 100, then I need to add the numbers form my phone book which are added newly.

```
private final ContentObserver contactsObserver = new ContentObserver(null) {

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);

            List<ContactLocal> totalContantsInDb = null;
            try {
                totalContantsInDb = getHelper().getContactLocalIntDataDao().queryBuilder().selectColumns("mContactNumber").query();
                String a = null;
                String b = a;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            getContacts();
            //showNotification();
            Utils.executeAsyncTask(new UploadContactsAsync(ContactService.this), null);
        }
    };
```